# SQL server join query performance with different where conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've two tables

> Student(Id,DatasetId and other columns)

and

> StudentAddress(Id, StudentId, DatasetId, Country and other columns).

StudentAddress has 2 foreign keys **StudentID** referring to **Student - Id ** and** DatasetId** referring to **Student - DatasetId**. Both tables are having 50 million records with one to one relationship with different DatasetId values.

```
--This query took 01:20 minutes
Select * from Student S 
LEFT JOIN StudentAddress SA on S.Id = SA.StudentId
WHERE S.DatasetId = SA.DatasetId AND S.DatasetId = 123

--This query took 01:18 minutes
Select * from Student S 
LEFT JOIN StudentAddress SA on S.Id = SA.StudentId
WHERE S.DatasetId = 123 AND SA.DatasetId = 123

--This query took 01:19 minutes
Select * from Student S 
LEFT JOIN StudentAddress SA on S.Id = SA.StudentId
WHERE S.DatasetId = SA.DatasetId AND S.DatasetId = 123 AND SA.DatasetId = 123
```

1)Will there be any difference in the performance between above 3 queries? When i executed these queries in my database, all queries resulted in same performance. I'm not expert to interpret actual query execution plan. Hence, reaching the experts to know which query will result in better performance.

2)Will there be any difference in the performance if I change the order of conditions in WHERE clause of the first query?

3)Also, my understanding is that data in both tables will be filtered on DatasetId and then LEFT JOIN will be applied on filtered data. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If you want to understand performance, look at the explain plans and try the queries on your data and your system.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your quick reply. I've included stats and updated my first question.

Comment: The first and last queries are identical (as you will see in the query plan). The middle query does something different to the other two (as you will see in the query plan)

Comment: I don't think you posted what you mean - double check your queries.

Comment: Thanks Nick for pointing out the issue. I've updated my queries. Where condition in the Third query will be the combination of first and second queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still... Queries 1 and 2 are different logically. The second query will exclude any NULL rows from SA that don't match.

Again, the question doesn't quite make sense because you are using and OUTER JOIN but then you go and filter on the outer table

So..

1) Query 2 & 3 are probably the same. Query 1 is logically different. If they were all inner joins I would expect them to all be the same

2) Order of predicates in WHERE clause makes no difference to performance

3) No. To prefilter before applying an outer join you need to include it in the `ON` clause

For example, these are very different:

In this query, records from SA might be NULL. 
`S.DatasetId = 123` will NOT exclude them

```
Select * from Student S 
LEFT JOIN StudentAddress SA on S.Id = SA.StudentId
WHERE S.DatasetId = SA.DatasetId 
AND S.DatasetId = 123
```

In this query, records from SA might be NULL. 
So, `S.DatasetId = 123` WILL exclude them.

```
Select * from Student S 
LEFT JOIN StudentAddress SA on S.Id = SA.StudentId
WHERE S.DatasetId = 123 AND SA.DatasetId = 123
```

This query does something again:

```
Select * from Student S 
LEFT JOIN StudentAddress SA 
ON  S.Id = SA.StudentId 
AND SA.DatasetId = 123
WHERE S.DatasetId = 123
```

With regards to questions 1 & 2, you can generate the query plan and note they are all the same (you don't have to understand it, just note it's the same)

In the end, database servers are configured differently so it's always possible that the query plans could be different but most likely not

Why are you using LEFT OUTER JOIN in this case?

Comment: there is a where condition S.DatasetId = SA.DatasetId in first query. Will that not exclude null records from SA? we are using entity framework and SQL generated from linq query has LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Sorry I missed that - yes it will exclude NULL records. So none of these queries actually require an outer join

Comment: Marked as answer for the clarification on my questions 2 and 3.